# How to use XML with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, xslt, model-view-controller, xml-parsing

I'm new to learning Rails and currently trying to complete a project for school that involves using of XML along with an MVC architecture. I'm using Rails as my MVC and I just want to know how I should approach adding in the XML and then rendering it to display that information.

I know that xml.builder allows me to build the XML using more DRY philosophy but I'm looking for a good tutorial that would explain the process of doing that and then display it in my browser. Any information is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify more, what you want to do exactly? you want to render data from DB and show it as XML or you want to read XML data and pass it to DB ?

Comment: I want to read XML data and then display it in my html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `from_xml` to parse XML data to hash:

```
xml = <<-XML
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <hash>
      <foo type="integer">1</foo>
      <bar type="integer">2</bar>
    </hash>
XML

hash = Hash.from_xml(xml)
# => {"hash"=>{"foo"=>1, "bar"=>2}}
```

**Reading from a local file:**

```
# reading the file content into a variable  
xml_file = File.read("my_xml_file.xml")
hash = Hash.from_xml(xml_file)
```

**Reference:**
https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/Hash/from_xml/class

Comment: Okay, I need a bit more information. Like which file do I place that into, does it accept an external xml file?